# Is it okay to change the name of the custom React Hook in 3rd party library?

Tags: reactjs, zustand

There is a rule that react hooks should not be used inside conditional statements. However, I found that if I rename the function when importing it, this rule doesn't apply. Using zustand, a third-party library, I avoid this rule as follows, but I haven't found any errors yet. When I create a `store` function in zustand it seems to be implicitly named `useStore`, but is it ok to rename it to something like this to avoid the rules of react hooks? Here is some code examples.

```
// zustandModule.js
import create from 'zustand'

const useStore = create(set => ({
  bears: 0,
  increasePopulation: () => set(state => ({ bears: state.bears + 1 })),
}));



// App.jsx
import { useStore } from '../zustandModule';

export default function App({ someBoolean }) {
  const count = someBoolean ? useStore((state) => (state.bears)) : 1;
//                            ^
// Error: React Hook "useStore" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render.
  return <div>count: {count}</div>
}
```

No error

```
// App.jsx
import { useStore as getStore } from '../zustandModule';
    
export default function App({ someBoolean }) {
  const count = someBoolean ? getStore((state) => (state.bears)) : 1;

  return <div>count: {count}</div>
}
```

Comment: React convention for hooks names start with `use`. Changing its name might make React not to interpret that function is a hook. Anyway, you should follow [React Hooks rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) (always calling Hooks from top level, avoid calling Hooks inside conditions, don't call Hooks inside other Hook (except useEffect)...) in order to avoid weird scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I have a project where I am using Zustand, and I have three stores to store three different types of data. (Note:) I typically end up calling them like the following in my components, for example:

```js
const themeClasses = themeStore((state) => state.themeClasses);
```

This doesn't raise any errors, and I think it's probably fine.

I am *not* saying this is a best practice, though. In fact there's a good chance its awful practice, but this is the first time I've been working on a project of this complexity in React and I didn't think I could wrap my head around Redux in time to stay on budget. However, I *do* keep to the rules of hooks: I only call them inside components, I don't call them conditionally, and I call them from the top. You definitely should not be using a hook rename to get around rules, you'll just end up with code that produces unexpected effects that will take longer to debug.